# VisualStudioCode (Mac) で、エディタをウィンドウいっぱいに表示する方法

Tags: vscode

表題の方法をご存知の方は教えて頂きたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

普段は上図のように２つのエディタを並べて開発をすることが多いのですが、
これを一時的に、

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このような状態で表示したいのです。

フルスクリーンではなく、ウィンドウの中いっぱいに表示する方法です。
例えば Eclipse では、ファイル名のタブをダブルクリックすることで、この表示になります。

どなたか、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 編集中のファイルを残して他を閉じれば(開いているのが1つだけの状態にすれば)画面いっぱいになりそうですが、そうではなくて「複数ファイルを開いた状態で任意のエディタを画面いっぱいに表示したい」ということでしょうか？ / "Ctrl + \" と "Ctrl + K" で画面分割をトグルするのが一番簡単そうです。参考: [VS Code の便利なショートカットキー - Qiita](https://qiita.com/12345/items/64f4372fbca041e949d0)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。やりたいことはおっしゃる通りです。ですが、その方法では画面が次々に分割されてしまいます。あれから自分でも調べましたが、そもそもそういった機能がなさそうです...

Comment: サイドバーは別途になりますが、「Code」ー「基本設定」ー「キーボード ショートカット」で「レイアウト」を検索すると、「1列のエディター レイアウト」というものがあるので、左の鉛筆アイコンをクリックしてショートカット（例えばCommand+Option+1）を割り当てると、希望の動作になると思いますがいかがでしょうか？　また、タブを画面内でドラッグ＆ドロップして、いろいろな分割や解除をすることもできます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。workbench.action.editorLayoutSingle で確かに希望通りの動きになりました。ただ、2列レイアウトから1列レイアウトにした時点で、各列で開いていたファイルが1列にまとめられてしまい、editorLayoutTwoColumns のキーを押して2列レイアウトに戻しても、右カラムが空の状態になってしまいます。。（右カラムにあったファイルが左カラムに残ったまま）質問には含まれていなかったですが、これも何とかしたいです...

Comment: 該当するissueはこれですかね: [Maximize current file/tab/editor #16927](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/16927)